# Computing the horizon profile given a DEM in Python

Tags: python, dem, spatial-analysis

Can anybody orient me towards an open source Python script that computes the 360° horizon profile (azi + elevation of highest topography in eye sight) from a single point (x,y,z) on Earth (account for a geoid model) ?

Such as this Matlab script, but in Python : https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/59421-dem-based-topography-horizon-model.

I use Python 3.4. I do not wish to use other tools other than Python.

Comment: you could access grass from python and to this tool : https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.horizon.html, but i understand you don't want any other tool... :/ juts in case.

Comment: `account for earth curvature` is hard enough. :)

Comment: Is there any progress in this issue? I'm facing the same problem now!

Comment: You could use [oct2py](https://pypi.org/project/oct2py/) and octave to execute the matlab script that you found.